# Portable command-line for syncing Windows OS clock to an NTP server

Tags: windows, command-line, ntp

Is there a "portable" way across recent (this millennium) versions of Windows for forcing an NTP synchronisation?

On Windows 7, there are even prerequisites - the service `Windows Time` needs to be running.

(Click the time in the taskbar → *Change date and time settings...* → select tab *Internet time* → *Change settings* → tick *Synchronize...* checkbox. This will start the `Windows Time` service).

After that, from an elevated command prompt, I can do:

```
> w32tm /resync
Sending resync command to local computer
The command completed successfully.

>
```

... but I don't think that's backward compatible. The [documented way for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_time.mspx?mfr=true) uses `net time`:

```
> net time /setsntp
```

...but on Windows 7 this gives the error message:

```
The /QUERYSNTP and /SETSNTP options have been deprecated. Please use w32tm.exe
to configure the Windows Time Service.
```

So, is there a way to make this happen regardless of Windows version? (If it can't be done in a simple command, then maybe programmatically?)

Comment: http://adamstech.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/use-a-batch-file-to-detect-windows-2k-xp-2003-vista-or-7/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use [w32tm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx) on all the Windows versions from Windows 2000 and on.

I tried running

```
w32tm /resync
```

on Windows XP and 2003, and the command works on them with no problem.

You can see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/time_w32tm.mspx?mfr=true) it is supported on Windows XP.

Also you can see it is supported in Windows 2000, [look here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216734).

Comment: It's good to hear that :)

Comment: `w32tm /resync` says "The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big." as my CMOS battery is dead and my computer clock resets on every boot at 1/1/2000 12:00 AM. Any help?

Comment: Found solution as per http://blog.bruteforcetech.com/archives/911 , do not forget to restart W32Time service `net stop W32Time` then retry `w32tm /resync`